# server function call on document observe changes

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code has the client call a meteor method. Then at the server, it attempts to insert a document in the collection `ActiveTaskCol`.
Then an observeChanges setup so that when said document gets inserted, a `console.log(fieldName)` gets fired in the `added:` property of the observer.

I am clueless as to why I am getting this server error. Thanks

> Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation

```js
ActiveTaskCol = new Mongo.Collection('activeTaskCol');
ActiveTaskCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = Meteor.userId();
  doc.createdAt = Date.now();
});
var activeTaskQuery = ActiveTaskCol.find({},{limit: 1, sort: -1});
var activeTaskHandle = activeTaskQuery.observeChanges({
  added: function (id, action) {
    console.log(action);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the sort syntax.  Maybe try `var activeTaskQuery = ActiveTaskCol.find({},{limit: 1, sort: {createdAt:-1}});`

---

but it turns out the next line will fail on the client since this has not been implemented in minimongo, but this might do what you want:

```
var activeTaskQuery = ActiveTaskCol.find({});

var activeTaskHandle = activeTaskQuery.observeChanges({
  addedBefore: function (id, action) {
    console.log(action);
  }
};
```

Comment: Your solution gives console error: Uncaught Error: must use ordered observe (ie, 'addedBefore' instead of 'added') with skip or limit

Comment: That's funny.  I didn't get then when I tried it.  What meteor version are you using?

Comment: I am running meteor version 1.2.1

Comment: Oh I see.  I only tested it on the server side.  Looks like this is not implemented in mini-mongo so won't work on the client: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2766